# How to delete Drawn Line in java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

The problem is how can I delete the old lines? I mean, make only the current x and y lines appear on the screen, make the intersection between both lines "follow" the mouse pointer.

This is the updated code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
public class SimpleGUI extends JFrame {
    public SimpleGUI() {
           this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
    }

    public void go() {
        Drawpanel = new Mypanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chasing Line");
        JButton mybutton1 = new JButton("Please");
        JButton mybutton2 = new JButton("Help");
        JButton mybutton3 = new JButton("Me!!");
        Drawpanel.add(mybutton1); 
        Drawpanel.add(mybutton2);
        Drawpanel.add(mybutton3);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, Drawpanel);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Drawpanel.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                DrawpanelMouseMoved(evt);
            }
        }); 

    }

    public void DrawpanelMouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        xpos=evt.getX();
        ypos=evt.getY();
        System.out.println("Coordinates : X :"+ xpos+"Y: "+ypos);
        Drawpanel.paintImage(xpos,ypos);
    } 

    class Mypanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintImage(int xpost,int ypost){
            Graphics d = getGraphics();
            d.clearRect(0,0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            d.setColor(Color.black);
            d.drawLine(xpost, 0, xpost, this.getHeight());
            d.setColor(Color.red);
            d.drawLine(0, ypost, this.getWidth(),ypost);
            this.validate();
        }

    } // end the inner class 

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Look and feel not set");
        }

        SimpleGUI win = new SimpleGUI();
        win.go();
    }

    Mypanel Drawpanel;
    private int xpos=0;
    private int ypos=0;
}  // close SimpleGUI class
```

The question is how can I keep those 3 buttons with out altering their state?

Comment: Do you want to clean the panel or just remove some lines?

Comment: What i would like to achieve, is make both the vertical and horizontal lines follow the mouse pointer with out leaving trace behind.

Answer (score 7):

> The problem is how can i delete the old lines?, i mea,make only the current x and y lines appear on the screen, make the intersection between both lines "follow" the mouse pointer.

- Save all your lines that you want to keep in a LinkedList or similar.
- Start painting with drawing the background again, this will clear your old lines.
- Paint all your lines in your LinkedList.

Or if you don't want to save any lines:

1. Draw the background again, this removes the old lines.
2. Draw your lines.

You can draw the background again with:

```
clearRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, but i hava another issue, if i button widgets(button,, text box, whatever) all get deleted, how can i conserve the widget?

Comment: @Jeyjey: What are you trying to do? Add your components to other panels, not the one you are painting on.

Comment: @Jonas Don't you think it will be too inefficient when there are lot of lines

Answer (score 1):

You should never use code that invokes getGraphics(). Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method.

[Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) shows 2 different approaches for doing some basic painting.

I'm not sure I understand your question about the "widgets", but the examples have buttons that are not affected by the painting.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to do `d.clear();` just after the `Graphics d = getGraphics();` line, this will clear the existing graphics and what you draw on it after that will be all that's shown.

Comment: thank you for you answer, but i hava another issue, if i button widgets(button,, text box, whatever) all get deleted, how can i conserve the widget?

Comment: not sure what you mean there? you probably want the thing you're drawing on to be a separate swing widget with buttons around/above it?